# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL

Tags: javascript

```
window.history.pushState({
  id: cat_id
}, 'Viewing item #35', SITE_URL + '?' + cat_key + '/' + brand_key);
```

> view_carrier_now.js:33 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http:// www.dmvbuyback .com/?iPhone/iPhone-5c' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://dmvbuyback.com' and URL 'http://dmvbuyback.com/index.php'.

Was working didn't change anything but some prices in the admin panel now its giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the value in `SITE_URL` doesn't match the current address. `SITE_URL` has "http://www.dmvbuyback.com/" while the current address is "http://dmvbuyback.com/". I did a little test in the chrome debugger and got similar results:

[image]

It looks like if you were to remove the "www." from `SITE_URL` it would probably work.